# Target Version of the .NET Framework does not match Launch Condition

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, windows-installer

I have a c# project that I am building in VS 2010. It references a C++ project through COM, which is also a part of the solution. Last Friday, I made a successful build, changed a single line of code, made another build, and I started getting an error about .NET.

The target version of the .NET Framework in the project does not match the .NET Framework launch condition version '.NET Framework 3.5'. Update the version of the .NET Framework launch condition to match the target version of the .NET Framework in the Advanced Compile Options Dialog Box (VB) or the Application Page (C#, F#).

- Project -> Properties -> Application -> Target Framework (for each project in both Debug and Release)
- Project -> Properties -> Publish -> Prerequisites (confirmed .NET 3.5 and Windows Installer 3.1)
- Setup -> Launch Conditions -> .NET Framework
- Setup -> Properties -> Prerequisites

I have also reviewed the vdproj code for my installer, confirming the launch conditions were .NET 3.5:

```
"ComponentsUrl" = "8:"
"Items"
{
    "{EDC2488A-8267-493A-A98E-7D9C3B36CDF3}:Microsoft.Net.Framework.3.5.SP1"
    {
        "Name" = "8:.NET Framework 3.5 SP1"
        "ProductCode" = "8:Microsoft.Net.Framework.3.5.SP1"
    }
    "{EDC2488A-8267-493A-A98E-7D9C3B36CDF3}:Microsoft.Windows.Installer.3.1"
    {
        "Name" = "8:Windows Installer 3.1"
        "ProductCode" = "8:Microsoft.Windows.Installer.3.1"
    }
}

"ComponentsUrl" = "8:"
"Items"
{
     "{EDC2488A-8267-493A-A98E-7D9C3B36CDF3}:Microsoft.Net.Framework.3.5.SP1"
     {
         "Name" = "8:.NET Framework 3.5 SP1"
         "ProductCode" = "8:Microsoft.Net.Framework.3.5.SP1"
     }
     "{EDC2488A-8267-493A-A98E-7D9C3B36CDF3}:Microsoft.Windows.Installer.3.1"
     {
         "Name" = "8:Windows Installer 3.1"
         "ProductCode" = "8:Microsoft.Windows.Installer.3.1"
     }
}

"LaunchCondition"
{
    "{A06ECF26-33A3-4562-8140-9B0E340D4F24}:_799EF2A78D074B669D0B30310FD56A67"
    {
        "Name" = "8:.NET Framework"
        "Message" = "8:[VSDNETMSG]"
        "FrameworkVersion" = "8:.NETFramework,Version=v3.5"
        "AllowLaterVersions" = "11:FALSE"
        "InstallUrl" = "8:http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=131000"
    }
}
```

Since I build for both an x86 and x64 compiler, I have two setup projects. The second one, for the x86 processor, does not get the .NET error. I have compared the code in its vdproj with this, and it looks the same.

I have found several threads on this issue, including a very good one [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformssetup/thread/5167197a-12a5-473e-940a-569e92f08f37/), but none of them have helped me resolve this issue. Any suggestions would be helpful.

**EDIT**

I changed everything to .NET 4.0 just to see if it made a difference, and the project built successfully. I changed it back, and it gave me the .NET version error again. I checked the vdproj file for any "4.0" reference, and only found it for the AspNetVersion, which also occured in the x86 version of the installer which works.

```
"AspNetVersion" = "8:4.0.30319.0"
```

I need to release with .NET 3.5, so this was just an exercise to see if changing the version to something else and back would resolve the issue.

Comment: Not completely related to your issue, but I noticed you are keeping multiple project files for different target platforms. You should check this out, might make your life easier: http://stackoverflow.com/a/145970/81193

Comment: I had my project similar to this previously, but the c++ dll was not registering correctly, and I couldn't access it. On a whim, I added it to the project and everything worked like a charm... at least until this issue arose. Thank you for the link, though.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It turns out that the C++ code was also associated with .NET for some reason. I used [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ff770576%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) article to help me change the c++ .NET version from 4.0 to 3.5. The basic steps are

1. Open the c++ project vcxproj in a text editor
2. Find `<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>`

   - This may need to be created under the Globals PropertyGroup
3. Change 4.0 to 3.5
4. Open the project in VS
5. Right click the c++ project and select properties
6. Select Common Properties and confirm that the version is 3.5
7. Select Configuration Properties -> General
8. Make sure the Platform Toolset is set to v90

Comment: Unbelievable! This was it for me (V3.5 SP1). For VS2010, I definitely had to add the <TargetFrameworkVersion>v3.5</TargetFrameworkVersion> within the Globals PropertyGroup, and #6 is not present, and #8 is v100. THANK YOU!

Comment: `This may need to be created under the global PropertyGroup` That solves it for me.

Answer (score 96):

To alter it through the UI (not a text editor). Taken from [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/5167197a-12a5-473e-940a-569e92f08f37/error-the-version-of-the-net-framework-launch-condition-net-framework-4-does-not-match-the?forum=winformssetup).

> 1) Select installer project
>
> 2) In Solution Explorer or Solution Navigator click on the icon at the top of the panel "Launch Conditions Editor" (In VS2010 its the icon with binoculars, in VS2015 and VS2017 the icon is a sheet of paper with a filter in front of it (shout out to Mat and Bob Van de Vijver in the comments).
>
> 3) Under Launch Conditions, Select ".Net framework" on the right in "Properties" Select "Version" you will see a drop down. change the framework to your target framework.
>
> 4) Build and install.

If you then receive a message similar to the following:

> WARNING: The version of the .NET Framework launch condition '.NET Framework 4' does not match the selected .NET Framework bootstrapper package. Update the .NET Framework launch condition to match the version of the .NET Framework selected in the Prerequisites Dialog Box.

Perform the following steps:

> 1) Right click the installer project and click 'properties'.
>
> 2) Click on the 'Prerequisites' button.
>
> 3) Change as desired.

EDIT: Updated the Launch Conditions Editor icon description for different version of VS, as per the comments.

Comment: In VS2017, the Launch Conditions Editor icon appears to have changed from binoculars to a sheet of paper with a filter in front of it.

Comment: The same is the case with VS2015.

Comment: Install URL contains http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=671728 for 4.6.1
can someone pls tell me how get this forward link for 4.8 Framework?, google gives the direct link.

Comment: Never mind got it 4.8 Offline installer link: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2088631

Answer (score 4):

Had same problem as this project had been converted from 2008 to 2010.

To change the bootstrapper, I opened the .csproj and manually removed instances from 3.5 in it:

```
<BootstrapperPackage Include="Microsoft.Net.Client.3.5">
  <Visible>False</Visible>
  <ProductName>.NET Framework 3.5 SP1 Client Profile</ProductName>
  <Install>false</Install>
</BootstrapperPackage>
<BootstrapperPackage Include="Microsoft.Net.Framework.3.5.SP1">
  <Visible>False</Visible>
  <ProductName>.NET Framework 3.5 SP1</ProductName>
  <Install>false</Install>
</BootstrapperPackage>
```

Also, I found out you can just right click on the Setup and Deployment project, hit properties, go to prerequisites, and select the correct .NET framework.

It was hard to find it, you have to click on the Prerequisites button.

Answer (score 4):

I was also facing the same issue.I made a mistake that target frame work was different at all places.U can verify that at below mentioned places same framework should be selected.I am using VS2015.
Place 1 - right click on Project->  Properties -> application -> target framework for me (.Net framework 4) you can select according to your project.
Place 2 - Right click on installer project -> properties -> prerequisites-> select microsoft framework 4 (X86 and X64) for u it depends which framework you target.
Place 3 - Right click on Installer project -> click on view-> launch condition -> .net Framework -> right click properties-> select >net framework 4.
I was working with windows services and facing this issue while updating from vs 2010 to 2015.Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 4):

Even after setting the framework version and Setup project prerequisites in all the places mentioned above. The error continued to appear. I then looked in the setup project file and saw the previous NET framework version was still mentioned under the Configurations/Debug section, so in Visual Studio I set the compile mode back to Debug, repeated the same changes and that cleared the error for me.

Comment: For those of you who tried all three steps and STILL get the warning, I found yet a 4th location! In one of your packaged projects (in my case, a Windows Service project, go to its Properties, then Publish, then Prerequisites, and make sure that matches your Setup project's Prerequisites.  What. A. Pain. This. Was.

Answer (score 3):

- On main menu select "Project"
- Select option " Properties"
- A form will open, select "Build", click on button "Prerequisites", select your .Net version.

Comment: This applies for Installer projects; it doesn't seem to apply for other project types.