# Created setup file in Visual Studio 2017 but not run software after installation

Tags: c#, winforms, installation, visual-studio-2017

For my program I am using metro dll file for design of my form application. while I build for creating file following warning is showing:

> WARNING: The target version of the .NET Framework in the project does not match the .NET Framework launch condition version
>   '.NET Framework 4.6.1'. Update the version of the .NET Framework
>   launch condition to match the target version of the.NET Framework in
>   the Advanced Compile Options Dialog Box (VB) or the Application Page
>
> ### (C#, F#).

And at last it shown success message. My .NET Framework is up to date. Should I have to attach .dll file differently? Please help me for this

Comment: can you tell us what is target framework of your application? and is it installed in computer where you are trying to run it?

Comment: Does this help?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15770318/target-version-of-the-net-framework-does-not-match-launch-condition

Comment: @Amit yes it installed in computer but the program is not opening after finished installation... should i have to do something for dll file ??

Comment: @Amit I am using metro dll. I tried to do another sample program it worked but in my project it is not working

Comment: @niksankaree , then i should be easier for you. try searching difference between two projects. one hint is there in link provided by Always Learning

Comment: @Amit the same problem is showing in another sample program too but that is working but main program is not running

Comment: @niksankaree have you added same dll references in another projects too? have you actually tried using of this dlls in that sample project?

Comment: [How can I configure what .NET version should be installed by windows installer in VS 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48850203/3110834)

Comment: My code is in  ascii form is that affect???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why dont you try to create file other than `C:\` Drive