# Compile a statement only if Assembly has specific version (x86 or x64)

Tags: c#, compilation, x86-64

I have a project where I reference a `third party assembly`.

That assembly has `x86 and x64 versions`. I can only reference one, since the third party system relies on a specific one to work. (Depending on wich machine the system is installed)

---

Until now, I could manage both versions in a single project using this answer. So, I set the configuration manager option to x86 or x64 and it knows wich version to reference.

[Targeting both 32bit and 64bit with Visual Studio in same solution/project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145803/targeting-both-32bit-and-64bit-with-visual-studio-in-same-solution-project)

---

But then I came with the following problem: Needed to use a method from that assembly having version specific parameter type.

The `x64` version has an `IdToObject(long ID)` method that doesn't exist in the x86.

The `x86` version has an `IdToObject(int ID)` method that doesn't exist in the x64.

The ID is provided by another assembly of the same third party (that is not version specific). The `ObjectID` class gives me the `ToInt32()` and the `ToInt64()` methods.

---

If I try the `IdToObject(ID.ToInt32())` in a `x64` version, I get an `overflow at runtime`.

If I try the `IdToObject(ID.ToInt64())` in a `x86` version, `doesn't compile` (trying to pass long as int).

I've tried this, runs fine for the x64 version, but doesn't compile for the x86.

```
if (System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().ProcessorArchitecture == System.Reflection.ProcessorArchitecture.X86)
    return Document.IdToObject(ObjectID.ToInt32()); //returns an object
else
    return Document.IdToObject(ObjectID.ToInt64()); //returns an object
```

So, all I need is to avoid compiling a single line when project is set to x86, and another if project is set to x64. What can I do?

Comment: Sounds like you might have to resort to using preprocessor directives? There may be another way but I don't know what it would be. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ed8yd1ha(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you will need to use a preprocessor directive. In your project properties for your 64-bit build configuration, add WIN64 under Build, Conditional compilation symbols. Then change your code to this:

```
#if WIN64
        return Document.IdToObject(ObjectID.ToInt64()); //returns an object
#else
        return Document.IdToObject(ObjectID.ToInt32()); //returns an object
#endif
```

Comment: The symbol can be anything you want. Feel free to reverse it, if you would prefer to add the symbol to your 32-bit build configuration.