# .NET application from network share with Any CPU

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, 32bit-64bit, windows-server

Our primary business application is written in a mixture of VB.NET and C# using VS2008. The back-end is SQL server Express 2005.

The application is NOT installed on client machines.  It resides on a network share on (currently) a Windows Server 2003 machine which also hosts the database.  Clients access the application through a shortcut, and there are additional server-side executables running as services which are accessed by the client application code.  It's an entirely 32-bit environment at present.

We are moving to Server 2008 R2 and SQL Express 2008, and will be upgrading some of our 32-bit Win7 clients to 64-bit.  I have set the Target CPU to "Any CPU" in the compile options of all .EXE and .DLL projects that comprise the application and have run PVerify on them all - they are entirely managed code.

Is this enough?  Will both 32 and 64-bit clients be able to run the application seamlessly?

Thanks

Comment: You didn't need to change the target CPU. If it stayed as 32 bit they would all just run as 32 bit on the 64 bit machines.

Comment: Thanks Matt.  Just to clarify, I haven't changed the setting just for this upgrade exercise - they've all been "Any CPU" since inception.

Comment: OK I misunderstood that. @c45207's answer seems to cover this then.

Comment: If you are using any 3rd party controls/reports/etc, make sure you can get 64bit versions of them. 2 issues I know of that effect a lot of users are Crystal Reports (does not have 64bit dlls) and connecting to MS Access on 64bit machine. (there is a workaround but you are not using MS Access so who cares)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The client applications should work in this configuration, assuming they are pure managed code as you say. You haven't said whether you've tested this or not, but testing shouldn't be all that hard. :-)

Note that 64-bit versions of Windows have the [WoW64 subsystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WoW64) that can run 32-bit applications, so you probably didn't have to do anything in the first place.

The question [What does the Visual Studio “Any CPU” target mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/516730/what-does-the-visual-studio-any-cpu-target-mean) may be worth reading, but it looks like that is already understood here. If you need to be able to produce both x86 and x64 outputs (for example, if you have unmanaged DLLs that need to be called into), the question [Targeting both 32bit and 64bit with Visual Studio in same solution/project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145803/targeting-both-32bit-and-64bit-with-visual-studio-in-same-solution-project) may be useful.

Comment: Thanks for that.  Yes, I'd read the questions you mention.  I've been careful to not use unmanaged code, theorising that the great benefit of MSIL is that it is JIT and therefore I shouldn't need to worry about "targetting" at all.  I'll go ahead and set up my server 2008 test rig now :-)