# Crystal Reports x86 + OLEDB x64 in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, crystal-reports, oledb

I develop an app in C# with visual studio for my company. I need to use both Crystal Reports 2005 (I need to use this version due a licensing cause) which only has a x86 version and OLEDB x64 because is the corporate standard in the workers workstations.

If I target x64 machines, the OLEDB parts of the software runs properly, but the CR ones no. If I target the x86 the CR parts of the software runs properly, but the OLDB ones no.

Is there any way to, for example, target the x64 machines in order to make the OLEDB parts work, and force the app to use the X86 CR framework?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Targeting both 32bit and 64bit with Visual Studio in same solution/project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145803/targeting-both-32bit-and-64bit-with-visual-studio-in-same-solution-project)

Comment: Sadly i don't think so... If i understand properly i need a x86 and a x64 version of the dlls, but in fact i dont have it. Both CR and OLDB use a MSI installer in the workers machines. CR are CAG registerd and OLDB is a COMReference. 
Does what I say make sense?

Comment: Just wanted to confirm that targeting both 32 and 64 bit will not solve the problem.  When both are targeted you will need to install both the 32 and 64 bit Crystal Report Runtime Assemblies on any computer that uses the app/report.  I believe you will need to either upgrade to a newer version of Visual Studio, or refactor your database connections to use the x86 framework.  I would recommend the upgrade route.  Its probably more difficult, but you're only going to continue running into problems like this staying on a 15 year old IDE.

Comment: I was afraid that was the answer. Thanks to both of you.